# How to print full float numbers instead of "1.01383e+007"?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I want to print out the full legitimate value of some large summation of floats, but when floats are large enough you get this notation such as "1.01383e+007".  How can you get the legitimate value?

Comment: What code are you using to print them out now?

Comment: How can you expect this to be possible in C++, let alone any programming language, when it's been proven to be impossible to do by hand?

Comment: look at `<iomanip>`, specifically at the flags `std::ios::fixed`, and the functions for `precision`.

Comment: What do you mean by "legitimate"? Be precise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Floats are imprecise by definition ;d

Comment: @trinithis: No, they aren't.  By definition, they can imprecisely store an interval on the real number line, but they can also exactly store a precise set of numbers.  And quite a few times you do find yourself operating in that set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important characteristic of floating point is that they do not have precision associated with all the significant figures back to the decimal point for large values.  The "scientific" display reasonably reflects the inherent internal storage realities.

If you want 10138300 (for example) to appear, use a datatype which has more significant figures, such as `double` in the C family languages for values up to 10<sup>15</sup> or so.  Or use an extended precision integer representation, such as `long` or `long long` depending on the CPU architecture and programming language or environment.

Answer (score 7):

I read your question to mean that you do not want to output scientific format. If so then you can control the stream formatting like this:

```
cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << thefloat << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` data type does not store the precise value, and hence it is not possible to print out the exact value.

In a `float`, 32 bits are divided between three distinct parts: The sign bit, the exponent and the mantissa like: `S EEEEEEEE MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM`

In simpler terms, instead of storing the precise "12345678", `float` data type will only store "1.23*10^7" (and `double` data type will store "1.2345*10^7"). Other digits are lost.

Maybe you can look into the "Big Integer" library in C++ if you are interested in the precise value of a large number.

Comment: Except that the exponent is base 2, not base 10, so `1.23*10**7` isn't exact either.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My original intention was to make the concept of exponents and mantissa easier to understand. It was not meant to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use a decimal library, e.g. [gmp](http://gmplib.org/); the "1.01383e+007" format are due to the way float are stored.