# countdown from large number

Tags: c++, precision

I'm working on a solution to the third exercise of project Euler, and I need to loop over the odd numbers below `sqrt(600851475143.0)`. But I can't subtract 2 from the number every time the loop iterates, it stays the same every time. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581551/1087848) that is due to how numbers are stored and that everything just above and everything under the decimal point is lost. How do I solve this? I need decimal numbers, so I can't use an int (which would not have been big enough anyway).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't use an integer type? Odd numbers are by definition integer.

Comment: Bad design @NPE. But I think this is a problem not only I have, I think there will be others that need huge precise numbers with decimal numbers.

Comment: you certainly can use `long` or `long long`, and float/double are *no more "decimal"* than int/long. As for other problems, bigint library would be helpful but you won't need arbitrary-precision *non-integers* for at least problems 1-100 :)

Comment: Okay. Next problem: "integer constant is too large for 'long' type" at `long long behemoth = 600851475143;` @AntonKovalenko

Comment: @11684 `long long behemoth = 600851475143LL` (notice LL at the end)

Comment: Thx! I knew it was my notation! @AntonKovalenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for odd numbers, and odd numbers are by definition integer, just use an appropriate integer type instead of floating-point maths.